Squid proxy not enabling HTTP request based on MAC address
I have a problem with Squid proxy not processing ACLs.
My IP is 10.26.98.4 and it is listed in restricted_ip_range
My MAC address is in MacExceptionList but when the proxy is ON I still can't access websites that aren't on the domain_whitelist.
Tried to reload, restart squid - didn't help.
Tried with reordering ACLs - didn't help.
This is how MacExceptionList look like:
A8:A1:59:FC:A0:39
##:##:##:##:##:##

This is my Config:
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

positive_dns_ttl 6 hours
negative_dns_ttl 1 minute

########## Custom ACL ########## 
acl restricted_ip_range src 10.26.97.0/24 10.26.98.4   

acl MacExceptionList arp "/etc/squid/mac_exception_list.acl"
acl website_allowlist url_regex -i "/etc/squid/website_allowlist.acl"
acl domain_whitelist dstdomain "/etc/squid/domain_allowlist.acl"

########## Custom Rules ########## 
http_access allow MacExceptionList
http_access deny restricted_ip_range !domain_whitelist


#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Include allowlist rules
include /etc/squid/allowlist_acl.conf

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

strip_query_terms off


Maybe try checking for the mac address first, then allow/deny based on the address, then check the ip address and allow/deny accordingly. Read this and try a single mac address with the format specified. https://forum.netgate.com/topic/36848/squid-filtering-with-mac-addresses/4 "acl aclname arp      mac-address ... (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx notation)"

unfortunatelly, didnt find any solution. I think i will try with clean installation of Centos and Squid.
